# Matlab: Stereo Calibartion App

Tags: matlab, camera-calibration

I am using the stereo calibration app and have been successful to calibrate the stereo camera with overall mean re-projection error = 0.32 pixels.

I want to find the position and orientation of the camera 2 in the frame of camera 1. The values which I am getting in **TranslationOfCamera2** are not equivalent to the extrinsic camera-centric view shown in the app. Since **TranslationOfCamera2** is not correct, I dont trust the values of **RotationOfCamera2**.

You can check the camera-centric view [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKbHg.png) and the values for **TranslationOfCamera2** and **RotationOfCamera2** [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGsg7.png).

According to the figure, camera 2 is in +Z direction and +Y direction relative to camera 1. But in **TranslationOfCamera2** vector, the values of Y and Z are negative. This is the part which I dont understand.

Can anyone please explain the logic behind these values? In which reference frames are these values calculated? In the documentation it states that this app gives the position and orientation of camera 2 relative to camera 1. But in my case, I think, it is the other way around. Any help is appreciated !!

Thanks in advance !!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to first part of the question**

The translation of camera 2 is relativ to the coordinates of camera 2, meaning that if you would add (so basically substract because they are negative) the translationofcamera2 to the coordinates of camera 2, then it would be at the point of  camera one. Looks quit logical to me.

I know its not a full answer to this question but I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help. My doubt is that since the coordinates of camera 2 are in the frame of camera 1(according to the documentation), then shouldn't the translation be according to that frame? That means Y and Z coordinates (of camera 2 in the frame of camera 1) should be positive without adding or subtracting anything.

Comment: isnt that just the otherway round so basically what you are looking for is "minus translationofcamera2" ?

Comment: I dont think so because in the documentation it says that in stereo camera calibration, the reference frame is assumed to be at optical center of camera 1 and no frame is assumed to be at camera 2.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: `RotationOfCamera2` and `TranslationOfCamera2` are the extrinsics of camera 2 relative to camera 1's coordinate system. If you have a point `[X, Y, Z]` in camera 1's coordinates, its projection into camera 2 is given by `[X, Y, Z, 1] * [RotationOfCamera2; TranslationOfCamera2] * K`, where K is the intrinsic matrix of camera 2.

What you are looking for is the location of camera 2 in camera 1's coordinate system, which can be computed as follows
`-TranslationOfCamera2 * RotationOfCamera2'`.

That is what you see in the camera-centric plot.

Comment: So you mean that I should take the inverse of **TranslationOfCamera2** and multiply with the value obtained for **RotationOfCamera2** (without taking its inverse)?

Comment: @KamalDSOberoi, no, you should take the inverse of `RotationOfCamera2`.  That's what the apostrophe is for. It's a rotation matrix, so its transpose is its inverse.